# How to be Notified when a Thread is Created in the System

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, pthreads, posix

I would like to create a C/C++ program that is informed in "real-time" *(i.e. as fast as possible)* when a thread is created in the system *(not in the current process)*:

- new thread in an existing process
- new process

*I would like a solution working on Linux. Even better if it is portable on any UNIX.*

- Is there a POSIX API that I can use?
- Is it possible to get this information from "anywhere" in `/sys/kernel`?
- Any other solution?

Comment: How about `inotify` on `/proc`?

Answer (score 5):

There are no POSIX interfaces for anything related to system monitoring/administration/whatever and probably there are no de facto portable interfaces of the sort either. Most definitely there is nothing portable to get notified about arbitrary thread creation.

There are 2 basic things you can do on Linux:

- so called [proc connector](http://netsplit.com/the-proc-connector-and-socket-filters). Personally, I've never played with it, but apparently it kind of works
- [systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/)

However, I strongly suggest you explain what do you need/want this for. A crucial note is that whatever was created can be gone before you get to act on the information (apart from systemtap case, as long as you keep all the actions within the probe).

Comment: Also, it seems likely that you'd have to modify the system shared library or something similar to get existing programs to play ball.  Prebuilt software won't be built to use any interface you devise, so you have to achieve interposition.  I also wonder if the OP has any idea how many threads can be generated per second on a busy system.

Comment: The proc connector is a kernel-level mechanism and systemtap can be used on both kernel- and user- level probes. I thought it is implicit that you should place the probe on the kernel side. A bonus side-effect is that this also covers containers, although that's probably not a factor in OP's case. The best place to put the probe on is left as an exercise. Looking at the collection of scripts at the homepage and a little bit of kernel code reading should easily give an answer.